# node(10020) How do i remove 'MongoError' warning?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mocha.js

If i run my `mocha` test i'm getting this warning message:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\mongoTube>npm run test

> mongotube@1.0.0 test C:\Users\user\Desktop\mongoTube
> mocha

(node:10020) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)


  Create records
    √ Create a user in DB


  1 passing (68ms)
```

How can i remove it or solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue in *mongoose* source code that was fixed four days ago: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9900#issuecomment-802166493

Update *mongoose* to [5.12.1](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/compare/5.12.0...5.12.1).